# How do I select all emails in on Gmail Category (like the Social tab)?

Tags: gmail

I want to Archive (or delet)  all the emails in a certain Gmail Category (the horizontal tabs) like Social.

If I just select all, it only selects the ones that are visible. I want to Archive all of them.

Comment: Have you looked at the referred [Search Operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)? Have you tried the solutions offered? Did any work for you? If not we should find out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out you can NOT just do it the "normal way".

#### You can though by creating a search in the search box.

### How to select all emails in a Gmail Category (Social/Promotions/etc tab).

[image: Steps to select ALL emails in a Gmail Category]

**1. Create a search in the search bar: `category:promotions`**

**2. Select all by checking the selection box.**

***(As soon as you check the box you are presented with a message under it, giving you the option to `Select all conversations that match this search`)***

**3. Click on the message to select all** *(and not just the ones on the present page)*.

You will know that all emails in all pages are selected because you will be presented with the option to clear the selection.

[image: message after all are selected]

You can read more about *"[Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)"*

Answer (score -1):

When you try to select all the items on the first page of the category, it will give you the option to select all conversations.

[image: screenshot]